# gdb: apply "next" to selected frame instead of innermost frame

Tags: c, linux, gdb

In `gdb`, when you run `next` command. It apply to innermost frame instead of selected frame. How to ask to gdb to break in next line of the selected frame?

For exemple:

Set a breakpoint in a sub-function:

```
(gdb) b subfunc
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400f09: file prog.c, line 94.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1 at 0x400f09: file prog.c, line 94.
94      void subfunc() {
```

Change selected frame:

```
(gdb) up
#1  0x0000000000400f7e in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe468) at prog.c:70
70          subfunc();
```

I want to stop at line 71 of `prog.c`:

```
(gdb) n
95          i = 0;
```

... but it stop line 95 of `prog.c`.

Comment: Provide more information. For debugging, only use `-O0` or `-Og` (preferred) optimisation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found what I want. `advance` allow to continue until a particular line. Thus `advance +1` do the job. It can be abbreviated `adv +1`.

Answer (score 5):

Since the question is

> gdb: apply “next” to selected frame instead of innermost frame

The accepted answer is "advance + 1" is not so correct, which only works if the next line of selected frame could be hit.

> advance -- Continue the program up to the given location (same form as args  for break command)

A general solution is:
Switch to the inferior frame of the selected frame, finish it and step the program.

```
frame x-1
fin
n
```

where x is the selected frame.

Ref:

- finish -- Execute until selected stack frame returns
- next -- Step program
- frame -- Select and print a stack frame

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [temporary breakpoint](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html) [offset from the current line in the selected frame](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Specify-Location.html#Specify-Location) :

```
tbreak +1
continue
```

Abbreviated:

```
tb +1
c
```

Comment: Not so bad, but `adv +1` is faster to type.

Comment: ... and `adv +1` work as expected if you execute  it again (by pressing `<ENTER>`)